# How do I setup a multi-option voting system using acts-as-votable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to use [acts-as-votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) to implement a voting system where I can supply multiple custom options - e.g. 5 buttons ('blue', 'red', 'green', 'grey', 'white').

I want my users to be able to choose only 1 of those colors, but I would like to be able to tally up all the votes (10 - blue, 4 - red, etc.) per item.

I feel like I would use vote-scopes, but I am not quite sure how.

How do I do this with acts-as-votable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem to be pretty straightforward:

https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable#examples-with-scopes

```
@item.vote_by voter: @user1, vote_scope: 'blue'
@item.vote_by voter: @user2, vote_scope: 'red'

@item.votes_for.size # => 2
@item.find_votes_for(vote_scope: 'blue').size # => 1
@item.find_votes_for(vote_scope: 'red').size # => 1
```

So you'll need a set of 5 radio buttons (for 5 colors) on your page for the user to select from, and send the selected params to controller where you'll create the vote with selected color.

Then you can check if user voted for this item and disable the future voting for it:

```
@user.voted_for? @item # => true
```

---

**Update based on comments**

```
params: {id: 1, scope: 'green'}

@item = Item.find(params[:id])
scope = params[:scope]
if ['red', 'blue', 'green'].include? scope
  @item.vote_by voter: current_user, vote_scope: scope
else
  # show error message
end
```

Comment: @marcamillion, did you had any luck with this?

Comment: given that I am doing this in a Rails App, do you think it is best to create a single `vote` action on my controller, or should I create an action for each type of vote? i.e. a `blue` action and a `red` action, etc. If I did just a `vote` action, how would I differentiate between the options? Just check params and do a bunch of `if` statements? That doesn't feel too Railsy. Thoughts?

Comment: One action and send the name of the scope.. then in controller put all scopes in one array and check if the scope in paramteres is in this array. For example you have 3 color, red, blue and green and you want to vote for green, scope param will be green: ... See updated answer :)

Comment: That looks interesting. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot check status of a scoped vote using @user.voted_for? @item
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119176/check-if-a-user-has-voted-with-scope