# Check if a user has voted with scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-votable

I am using acts as voteable to implement a web poll. With two choices it is simple to determine whether a user has voted or not.

```
@user.likes @comment1
@user.up_votes @comment2
# user has not voted on @comment3

@user.voted_for? @comment1 # => true
@user.voted_for? @comment2 # => true
@user.voted_for? @comment3 # => false

@user.voted_as_when_voted_for @comment1 # => true, user liked it
@user.voted_as_when_voted_for @comment2 # => false, user didnt like it
@user.voted_as_when_voted_for @comment3 # => nil, user has yet to vote
```

https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable

I need to has custom multiple choices and have implemented it based upon this:
[How do I setup a multi-option voting system using acts-as-votable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860555/how-do-i-setup-a-multi-option-voting-system-using-acts-as-votable)

The item above states you can check if a user has voted with voted_for? however this does include scoped items:

```
Poll.first.vote_by voter: User.first, vote_scope: 'blue'
User.first.voted_for? Poll.first #false
User.first.voted_for? Poll.first, :vote_scope => 'blue' #true
```

My question is what is the best way to determine if a user has voted when using scopes? Do I need to loop through and check each scope individually for each record?

**Edit 1**

Currently I have the following Poll instance method:

```
def has_voted?(user)
  ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'white'].each do |option|
    if user.voted_for? self, :vote_scope => option
      return true
    end
  end
  return false
end  

Poll.first.has_voted?(User.first)
```

Comment: From the answer you linked, what if you try:
`Poll.first.find_votes_for(vote_scope: 'blue').voters`?

Comment: Yes, but if I have a poll with 10 options, red, blue, green... then I need to check all 10 to each poll to determine if a user has voted in the poll or not. If I have 1000 polls and I want to know which ones as user has voted on it will be slow.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding what you're asking

Comment: OK, a poll has 10 options. I need to know if a user has voted on the poll. Do I need to check the 10 options individually or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should be able to call `Poll.first.votes_for` and get a list of the votes that have been cast:

```
p.votes_for
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<ActsAsVotable::Vote id: 1,
votable_type: "Poll", votable_id: 1, voter_type: "User", voter_id: 1, vote_flag: true,
vote_scope: "blue", vote_weight: 1,
created_at: "2017-11-05 22:12:52", updated_at: "2017-11-05 22:12:52">]>
```

With that list you should be able to check if any of the `voter_ids` matches the `User` you are looking for:

```
p.votes_for.any? { |v| v.voter_id == u.id }
=> true
```

Comment: Excellent. Can you explain the difference between your code and:
p.votes_for.where(voter_id: u.id).any?

Comment: Mine iterates through the results from the query while yours makes the query and checks if there are any results.  In fact, I would use your line as it's a little more efficient to just check the query results.